# How to match Field=Value in File with Awk?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file in the following format:

```
[ Field1 = Value1 ][ Field2 = Value2 ][ Field3 = Value3 ]
```

However, SOMETIMES the fields are re-arranged and moved over to a different column, i.e., Field3 might end up in the 5th column for example as follows:

```
[ Field1 = Value1 ][ Field5 = Value5 ][ Field9 = Value9 ][ Field2 = Value2 ][ Field3 = Value3 ]
```

I would like to extract out the Value3 of Field3, however, I cant predict which column Field3 will be in.

Is there a way for me to extract Value3 by matching on "Field3 = "?

I can't figure out how to do this with Awk. Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Could you [edit] to provide a [mcve]? It would help handle the request better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed  's#.*\( *Field3.*\)\].*#\1#' | cut -d'=' -f2
```

Demo:

```
$echo "[ Field1 = Value1 ][ Field5 = Value5 ][ Field9 = Value9 ][ Field2 = Value2 ][ Field3 = Value3 ]" |  sed  's#.*\( *Field3.*\)\].*#\1#' | cut -d'=' -f2
 Value3 
$
```